# Joomla 1.7 articles in category list not displaying

Tags: joomla1.7

The articles in category list are not displaying in Joomla 1.7. Even if I create many subcategories and assign some articles to them, they are not showing and it always says it is empty.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with Joomla 1.7. I spend a few hours trying to figure this out too. This worked for me: Go to your menu item with the Category List. Under Category options change 'No Articles Message' to 'Hide'. Save the menu item and refresh the front end page.
Seems to be a bug as that message is meant to show only when there are no articles, but instead it just shows constantly.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the list depth to display any articles in subcategories. Also, make sure the date range doesn't exclude your articles. You may need to check and make sure the articles are actually in the categories that you are displaying.